# What is the reason/origin of Sikha?

Tags: tradition, brahmins

I have gone through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikha) of Sikha.  However, I didn't find any information about the origins and reason for the tradition of Sikha amongst Brahmins.

Is it just as a sign of cleanliness(as stated by the wikipedia), or are there more in-depth cultural origins and explanation of how it became a tradition?

Comment: Shkha is integral part of nyasa procedure of any scripture you are reading, Shikha is belived to posses great power and so it is touched to establish a power source inside it during nyasa process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyasa_%28ritual%29, so that is why it is important to tie tuft or shikha during worship,reading of scriptures, nityakarma etc.

Comment: @Yogi Thanks for the info.  But, what I really want is how the tradition of Sikha originated?  Who used to use the Sikha first, and why?